# How to include a .sh (script) file in Mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to include a Script file (.sh file) inside a stored procedure in Mysql?
If yes, then how?
And if no, then why?

Answer (score 1):

Like @mu is too short said:

You need to install these UDF's from: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php
Here's the download link: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/lib_mysqludf_sys_0.0.3.tar.gz

Note that you shell commands will run with the privileges of the MySQL user, not with the privileges of the user that's connecting to MySQL.
For a security point of view this is probably a bad idea.

**Note the warning in the link:**

> A Note of Caution
>   Be very careful in deciding whether you need this function. UDFs are available to all database users - you cannot grant EXECUTE privileges for them. As the commandstring passed to sys_exec can do pretty much everything, exposing the function poses a very real security hazard.
>
> Even for a benign user, it is possible to accidentally do a lot of damage with it. The call will be executed with the privileges of the os user that runs MySQL, so it is entirely feasible to delete MySQL's data directory, or worse.
>
> The function is intended for specialized MySQL applications where one needs extended control over the operating system. Currently, we do not have UDF's for ftp, email and http, and this function can be used to implement such functionality in case it is really necessary (datawarehouse staging areas could be a case in example).
>
> You have been warned! If you don't see the hazard, please don't try to find it; just trust me on this.
>
> If you do decide to use this library in a production environment, make sure that only specific commands can be run and file access is limited by using AppArmor.